# FormGroup patchvalue() function doesn't trigger input event

Tags: angular

I have a FormGroup for credit card inputs. And for formatting inputs, I have a directive with selector 'appCreditCardFormat'. Simplified version is below:

```
<input
    formControlName="cardNo" 
    appCreditCardFormat
>
```

appCreditCardFormat listens events as shown below and formats input:

```
  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
  onChangeInput = (creditCardNo: string) => {...}
```

I save the state of this input. Whenever user comes to the page of this input I use patchValue() function of FormGroup to set previously entered value. On the component, I check if previous value is present, then patchvalue:

```
    const componentState = this.mediator.stateSnapshots.getState(this._componentState);
    if (componentState) {
        formGroup.patchValue(componentState!.getFormSnapshot(), { emitEvent: true });
    }
```

But the problem starts here. Even though I see correct value, I don't see it in correct format. For example, I need to see in this format "4123 4245..." but instead I see this value onscreen "41234245...". Because the **HostListener** on **appCreditCardFormat** doesn't catch input event. If I change value after patchValue() input event triggers, and I see the input with correct format again.

I don't know much about but it seems like an Angular bug. I would be happy with any suggesstions.

example: [playground link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rqvmka?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: My first suggestion would be to not update the input value when the user is typing. Nothing is more infuriating than that.

Comment: Actually I access ControlValueAccessor in that directive. Not actually updating user input but visually it updates on UI. And this is the requirement of company, not in my control sadly.

Comment: That's the correct approach indeed ! Your directive seemed to update the value, not the UI, hence my comment. Would you be able to provide a [mcve] of your issue ?

Comment: I added the example to the question. That's clearly explicit.

Comment: 1) It's not complete and 2) we can't play with it. Also 3) [it's required](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But suit yourself !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your host listener listens to the input change value, not the actual control value accessor itself.

[Here is a demo example, working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xxwsqx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts%3AL11,src%2Fapp%2Fformat.directive.ts%3AL13)

You have to understand that the HTML Input element is **NOT** a form control : the form control is an Angular concept, that too listens to the input.

This means that when you update the value on the input **by hand**, it works, but when you do it from the form control, the input is **not changed**.

Also, you will see that if you put back the code in the ngOnInit of the app component, it will still not work : that's because the directive is created AFTER its parent. I would suggest you implement a REAL control value accessor on this component.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the answer clearly explains!